# How to avoid this Force Cast

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I think that a force cast I have in my app is causing it to crash, (userDefaults.value(forKey: "timeDiffSecondsDefault") as! Int?)...but I really don't know how to avoid it.  Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

```
func getProductionTime(store: Bool = false) {

    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

    let productionTimeFormatter = DateFormatter()
    productionTimeFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: defaultTimeZone)
    productionTimeFormatter.dateFormat = defaultTimeFormat

    if let defaultTimeDiffSeconds: Int = userDefaults.value(forKey: "timeDiffSecondsDefault") as! Int? {
        timeDiffSeconds = defaultTimeDiffSeconds
    }
    let productionTime = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: timeDiffSeconds, to: Date())!
    if store {
        storeDateComponents(nowProdTime: productionTime)
    }
    productionTimeString = productionTimeFormatter.string(from: productionTime)
    liveCounterButton.setTitle(productionTimeString, for: .normal)

}
```

Comment: `as? Int` would be how you do a non-forced cast, for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Use the dedicated API which returns a non-optional

```
timeDiffSeconds = userDefaults.integer(forKey: "timeDiffSecondsDefault")
```

If a default value != 0 is required [register](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1417065-register) it.

---

Note: Never use `value(forKey` with `UserDefaults` unless you really need KVC

Comment: thank you so much.  I'll go through the rest of my code to make sure I don't

Comment: This will return `0` if the value is absent. Which may be confusing if the real value is zero. Wouldn't `as? Int` be more appropriate?

Comment: @Carpsen90 Yes, it does. In most cases it's sufficient. If you really need an optional consider to use another type

Comment: @Carpsen90 or check if `objectForKey`
 returns nil.  `object(forKey: "timeDiffSecondsDefault") as? Int`

Answer (score 0):

When the key is absent, you are trying to force-cast an empty `Any?` to `Int?`, and thus, the if condition is not executed:

```
if let defaultTimeDiffSeconds: Int = userDefaults.value(forKey: "timeDiffSecondsDefault") as! Int? {
    timeDiffSeconds = defaultTimeDiffSeconds
}
```

And if `timeDiffSeconds` was not initialized elsewhere, it will cause the crash when you try to use it.

The appropriate way would be conditional casting with `as?`:

```
if let defaultTimeDiffSeconds = userDefaults.object(forKey: "timeDiffSecondsDefault") as? Int { ... }
```

[`object(forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1410095-object) was kindly suggested by [Mr Leonardo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2303865/leo-dabus).

Using `userDefaults.integer(forKey: "timeDiffSecondsDefault")` might be confusing when using `timeDiffSeconds` later, since `integer(forKey:)` would return `0` if the key is absent in user defaults, and returns an integer even if the value is a string or a boolean.